nextjs promises wont fire to backend but works after restaring browser
So im new to nextjs i have login page setup the problem is after a while if i log out and then do login again, the request is stuck on pending like this picture
but if i restart my browser and do login again it works, and after a few hours this behavior will happen again. So I needed to restart my browser every few minutes/hours
i dont know what is wrong, is it my local machine or the API, or the nextjs itself.
BTW I use PocketBase for authentication.
this is the snippet code for login page
login/page.tsx
export default function Login() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isAuthenticating, setIsAuthenticating] = useState(false);
  const form = useForm<LoginFormInputs>({
    resolver: zodResolver(loginSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    },
  });
  const route = useRouter();
  
  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<LoginFormInputs> = async (data) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setIsAuthenticating(true); // Set authenticating state
    try {
      const goLogin = await login(data.email, data.password);
      if(isErrorResponse(goLogin)) {
        if(goLogin.code === 400) {
          toast({title: "Uh Oh!", description: "Invalid login credentials", variant: "destructive"}); 
        }
        if(goLogin.token) {
          toast({title: "Nice!", description: "Login successfully, redirecting.", variant: "success"}); 
          route.push('/dashboard');
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return;
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setIsAuthenticating(false);
    }
  };

  const handleLoginWithGoogle = async () => {
    setIsAuthenticating(true);
    try {
      await loginWithGoogle();
      toast({title: "Nice!", description: "Login successfully, redirecting.", variant: "success"}); 
      route.push('/dashboard');
    } catch (error) {
      return toast({title: "Nice!", description: "Login successfully, redirecting.", variant: "success"}); 
    } finally {
      setIsAuthenticating(false);
    }
  };
return (<div>....my_code<div/>)

// auth.ts
import pb from "./pocketbase";
import { userlog } from "./userlog";

export const login = async (email: string, password: string) => {
    try {
        pb.authStore.clear();
        const res = await pb.collection('users').authWithPassword(
            email,
            password,
        );
        if(!res.token) {
            return {"code": 400, "message": "Invalid login credentials","data": {}}
        }
        await userlog("login_success");
        return {"code": 200, "message": "Login successfully","token": res.token}
    } catch (error) {
        return {"code": 400, "message": "Invalid login credentials","data": {}}
    }
}

export const loginWithGoogle = async () => {
    try {
        pb.authStore.clear();
        const res = await pb.collection('users').authWithOAuth2({ provider: 'google' });
        await userlog("login_success");
        return res;
    } catch (error) {
        return error;
    }
}


Okay, the issue is clearly around how you handle the authentication here. First, the fact the browser restart helps, says that a storage (be it browser cache, local storage, session storage, etc.) gets cleared and you can use the system again.
Now, there are several options to take a look at:

Try clearing the browser cache and local/session storage programmatically.
PocketBase might retain a stale token, leading to authentication problems. Try programmatically clearing it too.
If there are cookies in play, check network request to see if you're not sending incorrect information with cookies.

Hope that helps!
